# Why does gdalinfo --version show different outputs when run on terminal as compared to when run through python?

Tags: python, version, gdal

Why does gdalinfo --version show different outputs when run on terminal as compared to when run through python?

**Terminal:**

```
$ gdalinfo --version
```

GDAL 2.2.3, released 2017/11/20

**Python:**

```
import os
os.system('gdalinfo --version')
```

gives 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`os.system` returns the exit code, which can have a different meaning depending on your operating system. If you want to show the output of a system call, use for example:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.check_output('gdalinfo --version')
```